# registering bundle ID in Apple developer

Tags: flutter, app-store

I'm registering a Bundle ID and getting a warning like the one in the picture. please help me to solve it

[image: An Attribute in the provided entity has invalid value]

an error occurred when I added a new team, I don't know what my mistake was.
[image: an error occurred when I added a new team, I don't know what my mistake was.]

Comment: gimme some sample of what u insert

Comment: maybe the problem is because I logged in to the apple web dev user, it's different from the one used on my macbook? because I have 2 apple dev users.

Comment: what does it affect?

Comment: your Apple Id on your mac must be same as web, sign in with it and try again

Comment: I've tried adding team according to the web user in xcode but an error like this happened:

Failed to register bundle identifier.

No profiles for 'com.domain.nameapp' were found

Comment: did you change team in sign config and check auto option on?

Comment: I added team and checked automaticality manage signing

Comment: and what is shown on bottom of it?
can you take some screen shot?

Comment: I've updated my question. you can see in the second image

Comment: Ok, you need some test, change your id to something else for test to see what happen\

Comment: that's not a good way, I only have 2 apple dev accounts